GCP Dataflow brand new one-time window each time for the same key
Is it possible in GCP Dataflow / Apache Beam to create a completely new window with a different start date for the same key in a Streaming Job (on GCP PubSub)? For example, when a message with this key first time arrives from PubSub, a new window is created starting from the current time(time of this message arrives) with a duration of 7 days. All subsequent messages with the same key within the window's lifetime are included in it for aggregations. Once this window finishes (either by duration or by a trigger with X messages), when a new message with the same key arrives from PubSub later, a new window is created with a different start time (time of this message arrives). The previous window should be destroyed. This process continues infinitely.
The goal is to create one-time windows with different start dates (based on the timestamp in the message which initiates this window, and the specified duration) for the same key.

Hello @alexanoid, Does this Custom timestamp link1 and link2 helps you?
